# How to expose filters with dynamic values coming from another view?

Tags: views

I have a page on which I supposed to have content of a content type(view 1) and on its sidebar there will be listing of node titles of same content type(view 2). I am passing node id on click of node titles in view 2 and this is set as contextual filter in view 1. Is there any workaround to use ajax for refreshing content for view 1?

Comment: Please check http://mrkadin.com/blog/node/70 this is the solution for your problem.